# Normal subgroups orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group acting transitively and effectively on the space $X$ and let $J,K$ be two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=J\cdot K$ and $J\cap K\not =\{e\}$. Let $Gx_0$ be the orbit of $x_0\in X$ with isotropy subgroup $H$, can we decompose this orbit by $J$ and $K$ orbits, for example something like $G/H=J/(J\cap H)\times K/(K\cap H)$? What about the intersection $J\cap K$ action?

Comment: if $G$ acts transitively on $X$ then doesn't $Gx_0 = G$?

Comment: No, maybe the action is not free

Comment: effectively means if $g_1x=x$ for all $x\in X$ then $g_1=e$ and isotropy means the stabilizer of $x_0$ which is $\{g\in G; gx_0=x_0\}$

Comment: I guess effectively means faithfully, and isotropy subgroup means stabilizer. But if $G$ acts transitively then $Gx_0 = X$.

Comment: Yes, but not $Gx_0=G$!

Comment: I think the action on $J \cap K$ orbits decomposes as a product. So in your notation that would be something like $G/H(J \cap K) = J/(H \cap J)(J \cap K) \times K/(H \cap K)(J \cap K)$.

Comment: So how $G/H$ can be expressed?

Comment: @Ronald oops, yes, my mistake, I should have said $Gx_0 = X$ as Derek says